# Laravel 4 - How to access outside variables from an advance where

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a scope method in my model named Book.

```
public function scopeBookAuthor($query, $input = array()){
    if($input['book_author'] != ''){
        return $query->where(function ($query) {
                    $query->where('book_author_last_name', 'LIKE', "%".$input['book_author']."%")
                          ->orWhere('book_author_middle_name', 'LIKE', "%".$input['book_author']."%")
                          ->orWhere('book_author_first_name', 'LIKE', "%".$input['book_author']."%");
                });

    }
}
```

An error occurred inside the function in the 3rd line. it says `Undefined variable: input`.

I tried to include the input variable as another parameter but it didn't work

```
return $query->where(function ($query, $input) {...
```

Is there a way to make this possible? thanks in advance.

Comment: This depends on if you are after Eloquent ORM model objects or just arrays of the SQL results from using a query builder. You are missing a return value in the closure. And if the closure does not have access to the $input array, then you will need to pass it to the function.

Comment: You are also calling $query->where inside the function which is passed to $query->where( I would make the closure function return a vaild parameter for $query->where() or just delete $query->where( directly after the return and just return the $query object from the closure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a dirty hack:

```
return $query->where(function ($query) use ($input){
```